# Voltage drop, how much?

Tags: resistors, control, ohms-law, voltage

I'm making a 12 V test box for trailers. I just wanted to know if I add a load (let's say a 12 V LED light), will this provide enough of a load to show a voltage drop? I'm trying to pinpoint any resistance in cables under loads cause I've had trailers with very dim lights. Any info would be appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to have a load similar to the worst-case load experienced in RL? If the trailers have incandescent lamps and you test with LED lights you might need a sensitive voltmeter to pick up a bad connection that would cause issues.

Comment: Why LED? Would it not be better incandescent? A 20W lamp would draw 20/12 amps or 1.6 A. A resistance of 0.1 ohms will drop about 0.16 V. (First approximation)

Comment: Does a "test box"
 include the power source, or just the load and the car's battery is used as a power source? If it's the former, I'd even suggest using a short circuit as load, and a current-limited power source!

Comment: In my experience the bigest problem is likely to be the ground return connections.